# how to set website back-end administrator password without CMS

Tags: html, joomla, web, passwords, phpmyadmin

I am creating a website without use of CMS...I have used Joomla before and it has an option `www.mywebsite.com/administrator` that provides for back-end administrator username and password.

How do i set a back-end administrator username and password for just like joomla in a website that i created with `html5, css3, javascript, ajax, jquery, php and mysql`

Comment: Quick way to password protect a folder or site without using a DB is to use htaccess: http://www.addedbytes.com/blog/code/password-protect-a-directory-with-htaccess/ There are many tutorials for the traditional, php session and DB login method. Here is one example: http://www.phpsimple.net/tutorials/login_logout/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or you can just use an authentification login script

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tuto how to make an authentification script to your website : http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html